# How to ignore already crawled URLs in Scrapy

Tags: python, django, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a crawler that looks something like this:

```
def parse:
      .......
      ........
      Yield(Request(url=nextUrl,callback=self.parse2))

def parse2:
      .......
      ........
      Yield(Request(url=nextUrl,callback=self.parse3))

def parse3:
      .......
      ........
```

I want to add a rule wherein I want to ignore if a URL has crawled while invoking function parse2, but keep the rule for parse3. I am still exploring the requests.seen file to see if I can manipulate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out dont_filter request parameter at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

> dont_filter (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

Comment: Guy - Thanks for the answer(both!). I have already crawled a couple of links from start_urls. So some records are there in the requests.seen file for URLS while invoking parse2. Will 'dont_filter' work while invoking parse2, now that they have already been filtered?

Comment: dont_filter is per request, doesn't matter if the URL was filtered in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the rule in *settings.py*. Refer to the doc [dupefilter-class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/settings.html?highlight=duplicate%20url#dupefilter-class)

> Default: 'scrapy.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter'
>
> The class used to detect and filter duplicate requests.
>
> The default (RFPDupeFilter) filters based on request fingerprint using the scrapy.utils.request.request_fingerprint function.