# Problems Pausing and Resuming a Scrapy Spider

Tags: scrapy

I'm doing a very slow crawl on a moderately sized site in order to respect their guidance for web scraping. That situation means that I need to be able to pause and resume my spider. So far, I've been enabling persistence when I deploy the spider in the command line: `scrapy crawl ngamedallions -s JOBDIR=pass1 -o items.csv`.

Last night, that seemed to be doing the trick. I tested my spider and found that, when I shut it down cleanly, I could start it again and the crawl would resume where I left off. Today, though, the spider starts at the very beginning. I've checked the contents of my pass1 directory, and my `requests.seen` file has some content, even though the 1600 lines seems a little light for the 3000 pages I crawled last night.

In any case, does anyone have a sense of where I'm going wrong as I try to resume my spider?

*Update*

I went ahead and manually skipped my spider ahead to continue yesterday's crawl. When I tried closing and resuming the spider with the same comand (see above), it worked. The start of my log reflects the spider recognizing that a crawl is being resumed.

```
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5.post4+g4b324a8 started (bot: ngamedallions)
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ngamedallions.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['ngamedallions.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'ngamedallions', 'USER_AGENT': 'ngamedallions', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 10}
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: NgamedallionsCsvPipeline, NgamedallionsImagesPipeline
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-11 10:59:36 [scrapy] INFO: Resuming crawl (3 requests scheduled)
```

When I try to resume the spider after a second graceful close (pause-resume-pause-resume), however, it starts the crawl over again. The beginning of the log in that case follows, but the main takeaway is that the spider does not report recognizing the crawl as resumed.

```
2016-05-11 11:19:10 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5.post4+g4b324a8 started (bot: ngamedallions)
2016-05-11 11:19:10 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-05-11 11:19:10 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ngamedallions.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['ngamedallions.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'ngamedallions', 'USER_AGENT': 'ngamedallions', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 10}
2016-05-11 11:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-05-11 11:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-05-11 11:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-05-11 11:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: NgamedallionsCsvPipeline, NgamedallionsImagesPipeline
2016-05-11 11:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy avoids duplicate URL crawling, [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) and [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/settings.html?highlight=duplicate%20url#dupefilter-class) you can find more information about it.

> dont_filter (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be
>   filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an
>   identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use
>   it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

Also, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20415051/2207154)

Comment: Isn't avoiding duplicate URL crawling essentially the behaviour I want? It seems that duplicate filtering is enabled at the moment. My log reports `2016-05-11 10:59:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.74388.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)` after the first page is crawled.